# can't download PDFs using urllib and beautiful soup, 403 forbidden?

Tags: python, urllib, beautifulsoup

iam trying to download pdfs from a website using python scripts i came across this code http://pastebin.com/nRVXgmqF but it was written in python 2 i changed it to 3, i have no idea why this is not working and i would appreciate the help thanks!

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import urllib.error 
import os
import sys

try:
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError:
        print ("[*] Please download and install Beautiful Soup first!")
        sys.exit(0)

url = input("[+] Enter the url: ")
download_path = input("[+] Enter the download path in full: ")

#try:
#to make it look legit for the url
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

i = 0

request = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html.parser") #to parse the website

for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True): #find <a> tags with href in it so you know it is for urls
        #so that if it doesn't contain the full url it can the url itself to it for the download
        tag['href'] = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, tag['href'])

        #this is pretty easy we are getting the extension (splitext) from the last name of the full url(basename)
        #the spiltext splits it into the filename and the extension so the [1] is for the second part(the extension)
        if os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(tag['href']))[1] == '.pdf':
                current = urllib.request.urlopen(tag['href'])
                print ("\n[*] Downloading: %s" %(os.path.basename(tag['href'])))

                f = open(download_path + "\\" +os.path.basename(tag['href'], "wb"))
                f.write(current.read())
                f.close()
                i+=1

print ("\n[*] Downloaded %d files" %(i+1))
input("[+] Press any key to exit...")

#except KeyboardInterrupt:
#        print( "[*] Exiting...")
#        sys.exit(1)
# 
#except urllib.error.URLError as e:
#        print ("[*] Could not get information from server!!")
#        sys.exit(2)
# 
#except:
#        print ("I don't know the problem but sorry!!")
#        sys.exit(3)
```

im getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\random\Desktop\Pastpapers\downpp.py", line 33, in <module>
    current = urllib.request.urlopen(tag['href'])
  File "C:\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

## What happened?

i couldn't get the above code to work! i realised the error was coming from this line `current = urllib.request.urlopen(tag['href'])` so i just decided to use the requests library to download it.

### My New Working CODE!

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from requests import get  # to make GET request
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url           = input("[+] Enter the url: ")
download_path = input("[+] Enter the download path in full: ")
headers       = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
request       = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)
html          = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
soup          = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html.parser") #to parse the website

for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    tag['href'] = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, tag['href']).replace(" ", "%20")
    if os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(tag['href']))[1] == '.pdf':
        # open in binary mode
        a = download_path + "\\" +os.path.basename(tag['href'])
        f = open(a, "wb")
        response = get(tag['href'])
        # write to file
        f.write(response.content)
        f.close()
```

Comment: The error is not exactly related to the code, but to the website. You get a `403 Forbidden` when the website expects you to be logged in (authenticated).

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil this is the website : http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20A%20and%20AS%20Level/Physics%20%289702%29/ definitely dont need to sign up i want download all the pdfs

Comment: You should try printing the exact `tag['href']` element where the error occurs and try opening that in the browser first.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil so i put a `print (tag['href'])` immediately after the defined variable `tag['href'] `and i get a couple of links then an error

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil i dont know if thats what you meant , this is what is printed http://pastebin.com/EsJZb6pt

Comment: The last URL has spaces instead of `%20`; your browser will probably fix that for you on the fly. But the `urllib` library will not. Also, since you're upgrading anyway, I would suggest using the `requests` library. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: @jinksPadlock changed my code to `tag['href'] = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, tag['href']).replace(" ", "%20")` now the last link has no spaces but it still does not work , Error is here : http://pastebin.com/qrxuAkJg

Comment: so i commented out the last if statement and it printed out all the links on the page so the prob is def from this `current = urllib.request.urlopen(tag['href'])` , can it not open pdf files?

Comment: I haven't used `urllib` lately but calling requests.get works fine for that url. You would use `html.content` if you wanted to write the content to a file, for instance. However, `BeautifulSoup` won't parse the .pdf for you. Maybe `pdfminer` or `PDFQuery`?

Comment: @jinksPadlock i changed the code to use requests package, finally works now!

Comment: I knew I should have started with the "you should use `requests`" comment! :-|